# How to Submit appended form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a MORE button to clone forms everytime that clicked.and i want to submit each form with ajax, when SUBMIT button of each form clicked.How can i Submit each form separately with Ajax method?
Here is my codes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".More").click(function() {
    $(".MyForm")
      .eq(0)
      .clone()
      .show()
      .insertAfter(".MyForm:last");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="More">More+</span>
<div class="all">
  <form class="MyForm" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" value="Aynaz" />
    <select name="Avg">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `click` listener on each of the `submit` buttons you have, stop the default action (to make sure that specific form isn't submitted), and create new ajax for every form:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".More").click(function() {
    $(".MyForm")
    .eq(0)
    .clone()
    .show()
    .insertAfter(".MyForm:last");
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.MyForm button[type=submit]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault() // To make sure the form is not submitted 
    $('.MyForm').each(function() {
      console.log($(this).serialize())
      $.ajax(
        $(this).attr('action'), 
        {
          method: $(this).attr('method'),
          data: $(this).serialize()
        }
      )
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="More">More+</span>
<div class="all">
  <form class="MyForm" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" value="Aynaz" name="a1" />
    <select name="Avg">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

> Note - i had to add a `name` attribute to your text input (inputs without names are not being submitted).

Comment: i want to submit each form seperately without submit all forms. is there a way to do that?

Comment: This is what it does - it submit **each** form **separately** :)

Comment: yeah but i don't want Submit All Forms button.

Comment: Wait, you want that each `submit` on a specific form will submit **all** of the forms?

Comment: i have many records. and each records has a submit button. i want to click on submit  ,then submit only tthe record that i clicked.

Comment: i checked. but when each form submit. another forms will submit too